# Transferência de titularidade de uma "Property" do Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics-api, exportação, importação

A documentação sobre a titularidade das contas do Google Analytics não clarifica se é possível transferir a titularidade de determinadas `Property` do utilizador A para o utilizador B.

Encontrei [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6279152/352449) no SOEN dada pelo @Yahel, mas o [link para a página](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/72271?hl=en)  onde dizia não ser possível já não existe e a resposta data a 8 de Junho de 2011. Por outro lado, na própria resposta, existe a sugestão de que no Universal Analytics as coisas são diferentes.

## Problema

Até 2012, aqui na empresa utilizávamos uma conta nossa e criávamos várias entradas para os diversos projectos de forma a monitorizarmos a evolução do trabalho e podermos dar algum feedback aos clientes, estratégias de marketing, etc.

Mais tarde surgiram duas questões pertinentes:

- E se o cliente muda para outra empresa?
- E se o cliente vem a ter uma conta dele e pretende ser ele a cuidar dos dados do Analytics?

Em 2012, com o Google Plus já em grande uso, começamos a levar os clientes a abrirem uma conta na Google para efeitos de presença social e todos os novos projectos/Analytics são agora associados à conta do cliente onde nós temos permissões de administração.

Mas resta a questão de anos de recolha de dados nos projectos mais antigos que carecem serem transferidos para os clientes!

## Pergunta

Como posso transferir a titularidade de uma `Property` que está na nossa conta do Google Analytics para a conta do cliente?

<sup>Migrar os dados para outro *Tracking ID* que pertence ao cliente penso que vai dar ao mesmo efeito, pelo que também pode ser uma solução.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Zuul, infelizmente parece que no seu caso você usa a mesma conta para administrar propriedades de diversos clientes. Se for esse o caso parece que não há nenhuma maneira de transferir a titularidade da propriedade.

Se, pelo contrário, você agrupou propriedades em contas separadas (criou uma conta para cada cliente - todas administradas pelo mesmo usuário da sua empresa), assumindo que você controla tanta o usuário do cliente quanto o seu (por questões de segurança, já que você terá que atribuir privilégios de administrador para o outro usuário), existe um *workaround* sugerido pelo [Rob Maguire no fórum do Analytics](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/xDehvGxLgbE/Hm7Ftfo9WTwJ)

Todos os passos são feitos em `Admin -> Account -> Selecione a conta no Combo -> User Management` e em `Admin -> Properties -> Selecione a propriedade no Combo -> User Management`

1. Com o usuário originalmente dono da conta adicione o usuário do cliente como administrador da **conta**
2. Com o usuário do cliente entre nas opções de conta e **apague o usuário original** (para isso você antes precisará tirar os privilégios administrativos)
3. Para que o usuário original tenha acesso à propriedade, com o usuário do cliente garanta acesso de administrador para o usuário original a nível **de propriedade**.
4. Finalmente, com o usuário original delete a segunda conta como usuário.

No fórum o *Rob Maguire* explicitamente diz para você testar o processo com uma nova conta  para não arriscar perder dados, e também que isso só funciona para contas separadas.

Veja que isso não move uma propriedade, ela faz um jogo para passar uma conta (incluindo suas propriedades) para outro usuário.

Veja o artigo [Transfer Google Analytics without losing historical data](http://twotensolutions.com/move-google-analytics-google-accounts/) para um guia (as imagens ainda são da UI anterior do Analytics).